# Where can I find the documentation for JSF 2.x annotations?

Tags: jsf, facelets, jsf-2.2

I have downloaded the latest JSF 2.2 spec and JavaEE7 tutorial. In section 15.5.1 of the tutorial I find

> The renderer class begins with a @FacesRenderer annotation:
>
> @FacesRenderer(componentFamily = "Area", rendererType = "DemoArea")
>
> public class AreaRenderer extends Renderer {
>
> The @FacesRenderer annotation registers the renderer class with the >JavaServer Faces
>   implementation as a renderer class. The annotation identifies the >component family as
>   well as the renderer type.

I wen't through the specification and found no reference to "@FacesRenderer" or even "FacesRenderer".
Besides the javadocs, where is the reference documentation for JSF Annotations?

Comment: There is normal java doc for the annotations, since they are classes to: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/render/FacesRenderer.html. A good IDE will even help you with this

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm aware of the javadocs, but I meant to know if there's any reference documentation besides the javadocs which explain how a JSF implementation would handle the annotations.

Comment: Oops, I missed that you already went through the specs... Weird, there is indeed no reference in the 2.2 specs to this annotation.... Now I'm curious to. I know it is meant to be a 1:1 replacement for defining the renderer in the faces-config.xml, but only a redbook document by IBM has a reference to this

Comment: hmm... the tutorial mentions all this to, even that for the same component, the faces-config has precedence over annotations